# MVC password best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, password-protection

I have a login form with a razor field for password. 
My web site is over https.

Everything was working fine until someone added this code under OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) in the base controller :

```
        string[] keys = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys;
        var valueMap = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            valueMap.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[key]));
        }

        if (valueMap.Any())
        {
            sb.AppendLine("POST Parameters : ");
            foreach (var keyValuePair in valueMap)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("   - {0} : {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value));
            }
        }
```

And send an email to the support with the content of the string builder.
The password was include in the mail.

I don't want this situation to happen again.

What is the best solution? Is there something built in MVC4 to handle this case? 
Do I have to use JS Password encryption on the form?

Comment: Unclear what the problem is, what situation do you not want to happen again?

Comment: Simple solution would be to skip keys with the word 'password' in it, or something else which identifies password fields in forms.

Comment: Emailing content OnException seems like a really bad idea.  Why aren't you using the [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: When someone uses a secure site they expect their data (whether is a password or anything else they enter) to be just that. SECURE! not exposed just because your code throws exceptions. You should remove this code or get yourself a good lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, dont add encryption on the form, doing that would require you to decrypt the data before you can use, and that still doesnt really address the problem you are concerned with.  I'd suggest that you modify that exception handler to skip password fields.  If you site accepts credit cards, you might want to give those fields similar treatment as well.

Comment: Right now I have something like that, but it seams a little fragile to base it on the name

Comment: if your passing your data around using view models or similar, you could prob. work something out with reflection and attributes.  (I'd prob. try to do this) but I've never had a need so its not something I've worked out

Comment: I wouldn't skip them, I'd rather replace them with a fixed value. That way you can see that the password was present without learning its value.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Good Call, in other technologies when doing this I've done things like <NotNull> <Null>